# Rails delete records into separate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

In Rails, when a record is to be deleted, I want to maintain a separate table for such deleted records (that in structure would be analogous to the former).

One way to achieve this would be to obviously copy the structure, validations and associations from the first model and paste it into the deleted items model.  This would, however, result in a lot of code redundancy and is not a scalable solution.

> Is there a way to achieve this in Rails without much (or any) code redundancy
>   or a solution that might be more scalable than the one mentioned
>   above?

I am using Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and Rails 3.2.

**UPDATE**

I did consider using an additional `is_deleted` column in the table, however, I decided against it because I didn't want this table to get too big and messy with deleted posts.  I don't intend to really access these deleted posts - these are merely stored for record-keeping or archival purposes.  Adding this column would also make accessing this table slower and more importantly, I am afraid that I may miss the check `is_deleted == false` in some SQL condition somewhere - even if I include this check in the `default_scope` of the model.

Comment: This may be useful: http://railspikes.com/2010/2/26/acts-as-archive

Answer (score 1):

It is good idea to move them to separate table so that your primary table have less number of records and performance is not decreased by time.

Use Rails ActiveRecord Callback for deletion i.e.

```
before_destroy :move_to_trash
.
.
def move_to_trash
  Trash.create!(self)
end
```

In this way, when a record is deleted, its copy will be created in Trash table.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of redundancy, and is no different from the answer below by @Humming.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you want to keep the records and not throw them away. So you may want to just mark them "deleted" and tweak the logic in your code to not consider those records while retrieving them.

Comment: Well then you can go ahead and create an additional table for that. Since, you do not intend to access these records frequently, I think it is quite okay to keep them away safely. Moreover, I don't see any redundancy issue here. All you have to do is to removes the records from table A and put them in table B, whenever deletion is done. Since you wish to keep these records you would have to store them one way or another.

Comment: The redundancy is in the model - the associations and validations.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'deleted' column in your original table. Set the default scope of the model to exclude deleted records.